Why do i need to have reputation before i can vote?
I see some real good answers on this site but I can't vote and I can't comment. How do i get reputation points the quickest?

This question would fit better in the meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com area.

Wait what...? I thought this was about Bitcoin?!

Thank you for the notice! Actually, there is a flag for just this case: Below a post, you can click flag > Off-topic > "This belongs on a different site in the SE-network" > meta.bitcoin-se.com. You should already have enough reputation to use it, if I remember correctly. :)

@Jori, oh wow, I didn't even realize he said SO. :)

Thank you @Murch, I have not learned to do that yet and now you've taught me to fish :)

Glad to hear that. :)

Welcome to Bitcoin.SE. 
Reputation is a measure of your contribution to the website, and thus a measure of the community's trust in you. 
You can earn reputation by generating useful content, i.e. asking good questions or providing good answers. You can also gain smaller amounts of reputation by suggesting improvements on existing posts. If you haven't seen it yet, check out the about page for a short introduction to Stackexchange.
The help center has a section on Reputation & Moderation, which covers your question in greater detail, e.g. it provides an overview how much reputation you will gain for which actions.

Thank you so much Murch. Thats very helpful. I feel bad for asking the question now. I should have looked in the help first. However its people like you that give positive help that all of us will learn the most from. Thank you!

Don't feel bad, we've all been there before. :)
